Фильтрация данных в БД по дате и времени в django
Использую БД: PostgreSql;
в БД дата записана в следующем формате 2024-12-04 14:00:06.512458+03
Мне нужно отфильтровать данные в бд по дате и времени в следующем формате 2024-12-04 14:00, то есть ГОД-МЕСЯЦ-ДЕНЬ ЧАСЫ:МИНУТЫ. В фильтре Я НЕ ХОЧУ УКАЗЫВАТЬ ВСЁ ЧТО ИДЁТ ПОСЛЕ МИНУТ.
Я хочу вытаскивать данные из БД, которые были добавлены 1 час назад (сегодня дата), 3 часа назад (сегодня дата), 6 часов назад (сегодня дата), 12 часов назад (сегодня дата).
Пример 1, того что я пробовал:
import datetime

arg = datetime.datetime.now()
H = int(arg.strftime('%H'))-1
datetime_start = arg.strftime(f'%Y-%m-%d {H}:%M')
datetime_end = arg.strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M')

Model.objects.filter(datetime_puv__range=(datetime_start, datetime_end))

Никаких данных не находит
Пример 2, того что я пробовал:
Вся информация та же, поменял только сам фильтр
Model.objects.filter(datepublic__gte=datetime_start,
                     datepublic__lte=datetime_end)

Данные также не находит
Также пробовал поменять формат занесения данных в БД
в Settings.py  установил,
DATETIME_FORMAT="%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"
L10N=False
USE_TZ=False

При внесение данных, ничего не поменялось.
Помогите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать то что хочу?

Ну у вас форматы переменных отличаются
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> arg = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> H = int(arg.strftime('%H'))-1
>>> datetime_start = arg.strftime(f'%Y-%m-%d {H}:%M')
>>> datetime_end = arg.strftime('%Y-%m-%d%H:%M')
>>> datetime_start
'2024-12-05 19:07'
>>> datetime_end
'2024-12-0520:07'


